# docker port forwarding combined with ssh port forwarding

Tags: docker, networking, ssh, ports

I have a local machine LOCAL, a remote machine REMOTE, and a docker on the remote machine REMOTEDOCKER.

I have a proxy listening on LOCAL:12345. With ALL_PROXY=socks5h://LOCAL:12345, curl on LOCAL can use the proxy.

By `ssh -R 12345:localhost:12345 me@REMOTE`, I can also use the proxy on REMOTE through port 12345 on it.

Pretty much with the same logic, I would like to bind REMOTEDOCKER:12345 to REMOTE:12345 so than the proxy can be used in the docker as well. However, `docker run -it -p 12345:12345 mydocker` gives me:

> docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint laughing_blackwell (...): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 127.0.0.1:12345: bind: address already in use.
> ERRO[0000] error waiting for container:

How can I do one-way port fowarding in docker like `ssh -R`?